# Query from sqlalchemy returns returns Attribute Error: 'Nonetype' Object

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

In my application I want logged-in users to be able to schedule appointments with workers. So I made a wtform and had the choices option equal to a list returned by a function.

This is the code

```
class ScheduleForm(FlaskForm):
    def add():
        addresses = Address.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).all()
        choices = []
        for address in addresses:
            data = tuple((address.id, address.address))
            choices.append(data)
        return choices
    location = SelectField('Select your preferred address', choices=add())
    date = DateTimeField('Date and time of appointment', validators=[DataRequired()], format='%d-%m-%Y %H:%M')
    submit = SubmitField('Schedule Appointment')
```

However, when I start the server I receive this error

```
File "C:\Users\ANOINTING\Documents\Flask_projects\JobFair\JobFair\forms.py", line 112, in <module>
    class ScheduleForm(FlaskForm):
  File "C:\Users\ANOINTING\Documents\Flask_projects\JobFair\JobFair\forms.py", line 121, in ScheduleForm
    location = SelectField('Select your preferred address', choices=add())
  File "C:\Users\ANOINTING\Documents\Flask_projects\JobFair\JobFair\forms.py", line 114, in add
    addresses = Address.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).all()
  File "C:\Users\ANOINTING\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\local.py", line 347, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

My address sqlalchemy model is:

```
class Address(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(15), nullable=False)
    landmark = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=True)
    job = db.relationship('JobLog', backref='job_address', lazy=True)
```

Comment: The error message is clear: `current_user` is `None`, so in the line `addresses = Address.query.filter_by(user_id=current_user.id).all()`, the `current_user.id` part fails. You need to figure out how `current_user` is getting its value and why it isn't what you expect it to be. But you haven't shown us that part of the code, so we can't help you with it.

Comment: Current_user is a method from flask login that returns the data of the currently logged in user.

Comment: Well, what happens if someone makes this request without being logged in? You describe the error as occuring "when I start the server". Were you *expecting* this code to run on server startup? Maybe you should start by figuring out why it does.